# Use desktop-notifier python library on macos 13.4.1

Tags: macos, python, development

I am trying to send notifications using this [python library](https://pypi.org/project/desktop-notifier/). I have tried to sign the Python executable and my `main.py` file using codesign.

E.g. I have tried the following command `codesign -fs 'local_codesign' (which python)`.

However, I still get the message `Notification Center can only be used from a signed Framework or app bundle`.

This worked before and stopped after an update (not necessarily the last one)! How can I solve this issue?

I am on macOS 13.4.1 (22F82)

Comment: Which version of python are you using? I've certainly noticed some security "improvements" that stop me doing things in python. Maybe try using the Cocoa NotificationCenter APIs through pyObjC. Or put the code in an Automator workflow or Shortcut. Make sure you send feedback to Apple.